# Sentiment Analysis using RNTN

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis

I am new in python and want to do a sentiment analysis for my project. I found codes which uses RNTN approach for sentiment analysis of movie reviews.
Link: 
https://github.com/awni/semantic-rntn

But I am not able to run these codes. I am using windows, do some codes are giving indentation error. Can someone please provide a procedure to run these codes. In the end, I want to run this procedure on my own dataset which contain cleaned tweets. I know its lame to ask this question but I am stuck in middle and don't have much time to do a deep study. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do to avoid Windows errors, is install https://www.virtualbox.org and run Ubuntu in a virtual environment.

Ubuntu comes with both versions of Python installed by default and is much easier to work with for coding.

Also making those codes work will be a cakewalk.

This is the fastest way to get your stuff working.